# How to avoid an external HDD (USB-Drive) to mount automatcilly

Tags: 12.04, usb, mount, hard-drive, scripts

I do have an external HDD which is partitioned (5 Partitions) and i usually only use one or two of the 5 partations therefore i have no interest that once i plug-in the usb the 5 partitions are automatically mounted.

Is there a possibility to avoid or to select which partitions could be mounted automatically, whit the free option to mount the other partitions (if needed) at any time later?

I'm not a good programmer therefore i'm looking for an easy solution or an easy script!

Comment: It would also be great if one could add 'known' devices to Nautilus, and to define the specific behaviour for each.

Comment: It can be done with udev rules. To mount only some partitions and ignore the other.

Comment: @Pilot6 can you give me an example or a helpful link?

Comment: Here is the working answer: http://askubuntu.com/q/670991/367165