# Ignore one partition of two of an USB stick via udev

Tags: 15.04, usb-drive, udev, ubuntu-gnome

I have a USB stick with two partitions. After plugging the stick I use the following command to find the device.

```
dmesg
```

*Example output*

```
[11195.236020] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[11195.375432] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
[11195.375436] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[11195.375439] usb 2-2: Product: Mass Storage
[11195.375441] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[11195.375444] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 605DD851
[11195.375968] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11195.376732] scsi host10: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[11196.377830] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[11196.378159] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[11196.379647] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] 15769600 512-byte logical blocks: (8.07 GB/7.51 GiB)
[11196.381548] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[11196.381552] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[11196.383579] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[11196.390454]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2
[11196.394696] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Therefore, my device is **`/sdc`** and my partitions **`/dev/sdc1`** and **`/dev/sdc2`**

---

I used the both commands to get their UUIDs

```
udevadm info /dev/sdc1 | grep ID_FS_UUID=
```

*Example output*

```
E: ID_FS_UUID=dbf323e9-8d63-444c-9c11-76b9b9a0fed4
```

and

```
udevadm info /dev/sdc2 | grep ID_FS_UUID=
```

*Example output*

```
E: ID_FS_UUID=0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c
```

Therefore my UUIDs are **`dbf323e9-8d63-444c-9c11-76b9b9a0fed4`** and **`0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c`**

or per partition

`/dev/sdc1` >> **dbf323e9-8d63-444c-9c11-76b9b9a0fed4**
`/dev/sdc2` >> **0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c**

---

Now I created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/100-myusb.rules`

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/100-myusb.rules
```

and added the rule below

```
KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

and restarted `udev`

```
sudo service udev restart
```

But after plugging the stick again, both partitions are shown in <kbd>Files</kbd> aka <kbd>Nautilus</kbd>

What I'm doing wrong?

---

***Edit So 6. Sep 21:07:50 CEST 2015***

The rule

```
KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /tmp/folder1"
```

creates the folder `/tmp/folder1`

And for @Sneetsher

```
KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c", RUN+="/usr/bin/env > /tmp/udev-partition-env.log"
```

works, but the output file is `env_root.output`? o_O

---

***Edit Mo 7. Sep 20:31:06 CEST 2015***

Tested and doesn't works

```
KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0", ENV{UDISKS_SYSTEM}="0"
```

and

```
KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0"
```

Comment: @Sneetsher updated ...

Comment: `udev-partition-env.log` is not created then some thing wrong with rule match. try `KERNEL=="sd??", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'env > /tmp/udev-partition-env.log'"`

Comment: @Sneetsher But the folder in the example above is created

Comment: @Sneetsher The rule `KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="0eeb7004-8955-4358-a205-07d7376adb8c", RUN+="/usr/bin/env > /tmp/udev-partition-env.log"` works, but the output is `env_root.output` o_O

Comment: `env_root.output` ! I don't think so. AFAIK udev does not support output redirection.

Comment: @Sneetsher anyway, the rule is triggered, the other example rule creates the folder in `/tmp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28854/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-a-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Finally, I setup same environment Ubuntu 15.04 in a VirtualBox machine.

  ```
  ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="bf50cb5d-60bf-44de-9a8f-1bf74850a5a1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
  ```

  It works as perfectly as expected.
- :D I hate 3 digits prefix **`100-`** (common/standard is 2), So I'm using **`99-`**'s most the time. I never tried it before, renaming it to be similar to yours:

  ```
  # mv /etc/udev/rules.d/99-sneetsher-tests.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/100-myusb-sneetsher-tests.rules
  ```

  Voila! Now It does not work.

  The rule is overridden by other rules, pretty sure the system ones from `/lib/udev/rules.d/`

  You may try listing all rules files, to check:

  ```
  find /etc/udev/rules.d/ /lib/udev/rules.d/ -iname "*.rules" -printf "%f\n" | sort
  ```

  > **RULES FILES**
  >
  > The udev rules are read from the files located in the system rules
  >   directory    /lib/udev/rules.d, the volatile runtime directory
  >   /run/udev/rules.d and the local    administration directory
  >   /etc/udev/rules.d. **All rules files are collectively sorted and  processed in lexical order, regardless of the directories in which
  >   they live.** However,    files with identical filenames replace each
  >   other. Files in /etc have the highest    priority, files in /run take
  >   precedence over files with the same name in /lib. This can    be used
  >   to override a system-supplied rules file with a local file if needed;
  >   a symlink    in /etc with the same name as a rules file in /lib,
  >   pointing to /dev/null, disables the    rules file entirely. Rule files
  >   must have the extension .rules; other extensions are    ignored.

  **Source:** `man udev`
- May be this is the best way to check using **`udevadm test <path>`**, example:

  ```
  udevadm test /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host9/target9:0:0/9:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2
  ```

  Test it for both names `100-myusb.rules` & `99-myusb.rules`, you will see which order the rules files read and which rules triggered.

  **Reference:** [Which udev rule triggered?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213486/12209)